# Install Fuerte over Electric

Tags: ros, installation, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am thinking to install Fuerte.  I currently have Electric.

I would like to ask if I have to remove the Electric before doing so.  If yes, how do I do that?  If no, what will happen to those packages in Electric, which I expect will have duplicates in Fuerte?  I have also rosinstalled a number of packages in my user folder (in user/ros), which was done with "rosinstall . /opt/ros/electric package.rosinstall".  Do I have to do anything to these packages or can I continue to use them as they are (knowing that I will have to change some codes to work with new packages)?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45815/install-fuerte-over-electric/) by [owh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1754/owh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2012-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This](http://answers.ros.org/question/11285/upgrading-to-electric-then-what/#16747) was a similar question about upgrading from Diamondback to Electric, and pretty much everything from that answer is the same for upgrading from Electric to Fuerte. Basically, you can leave Electric installed, but you need to rebuild all of your source packages.

You could also look into [overlays](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays) to see if that would help you more in your current situation.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2012-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [owh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1754/owh/) on 2012-10-14**:
Many thanks!  The links are very useful.  I wasn't aware of them.  Well, I might have been doing overlays with rosinstall (am I?).  Has rosws replaced rosinstall?  Or are they two different things.  My apology that I am still trying to comprehend this stuff.

**Comment by [owh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1754/owh/) on 2012-10-14**:
As for the "recompile", I had been using rosinstall to install packages to my user/ros.  Can I simply "recompile" them using "rosinstall . /opt/ros/fuerte package.rosinstall"?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-10-14**:
rosws is part of the rosinstall package. It provides a command interface that many of us like for maintaining source overlays.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-10-14**:
To recompile, you should either check out fresh copies of any source overlays (recommended), or do a make clean in every source package before rebuilding it.

**Comment by [owh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1754/owh/) on 2012-10-14**:
Thanks for that important tip on make clean, joq.